# Как заполнить Expandable ListView данными из БД?

Tags: java, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite, expandablelistview

История такая - есть фрагмент (app.fragment) куда встроен Expandable ListView, на данный момент группы и элементы списков заполнены с помощью строковых ресурсов (хочется так и оставить, чтобы потом была возможность сделать перевод). Имеется БД SQLite3, как реализовать открытие информации из БД при клике на определенный элемент списка (то есть 1-ый элемент БД должен соответствовать 1-му элементу списка и т.д.)?

Код Фрагмента:

```
public class Fragment_Hormones extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter_hormones listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    //Переменная для работы с БД
    private DatabaseHelper_hormones mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment_Hormones() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment_Hormones.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment_Hormones newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment_Hormones fragment = new Fragment_Hormones();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__hormones, container, false);



        // БД hormones
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper_hormones(getActivity());

        try {
            mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
        }

        try {
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListView_hormones);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter_hormones(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return view;
    }
private void prepareListData() {

        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Добавить в заглавие значения из строковых ресурсов

        Resources res = getResources();
        String gipofis = res.getString(R.string.gp_gipofis);

        listDataHeader.add(gipofis);


        // Добавить в раздел Гипофиз
        String gp_gipofis01 = res.getString(R.string.gp_gipofis1);
        String gp_gipofis02 = res.getString(R.string.gp_gipofis2);

        List<String> gp_gipofis = new ArrayList<String>();
        gp_gipofis.add(gp_gipofis01);
        gp_gipofis.add(gp_gipofis02);

        // Header, Childdata
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),  gp_gipofis);    
    }
```

Код Адаптера Expandable ListView:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter_hormones extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter_hormones(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Код адаптера БД:

```
public class DatabaseHelper_hormones extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "hormones.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

    public DatabaseHelper_hormones(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        //InputStream mInput = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.info);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: реляционные БД не имеют понятия "первый элемент списка", "второй" и тд. (строки в БД не обязательно будут распологаться по порядку), они имеют только уникальные идентификаторы строки. Вам нужно либо группы и элементы так же хранить в БД и устанавливать связи с дополнительной информацией через эти уникальные идентификаторы, либо в БД делать дополнительный столбец с номером, соответствующим позиции в списке и по этому номеру делать выборку

Comment: @pavlofff, а если группы и элементы хранить в БД, будет возможность через условие в зависимости от языка устройства подключать скажем БД_rus или БД_eng ?

Comment: можно просто создать несколько таблиц с разными языками и читать из нужной в зависимости от локали

Comment: @pavlofff а пример реализации есть какой-нибудь? хоть что-то похожее, в интернете ничего близкого не нашел

Comment: Проще всего будет создать несколько баз данных, каждая со своим переводом. При создании БД в `onCreate()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` имя БД брать из строкового ресурса. Соответственно в ресурсах для нужных локлей указать имя локализированной БД, например для русского: res/values-ru/strings.xml -> `bd_name = database_ru.db`

Comment: или таким же образом одна БД, но несколько таблиц с разными локалями (*name_ru*, *name_en*, *title_ru*, *title_en* и тп: *res/values-ru/strings.xml* -> `name = name_ru`), тогда уже в запросах к БД указывать именем таблицы строковый ресурс (`SELECT * FROM context.getResources(R.string.name)`), который будет взят из нужной локали - такой способ позволяет менять локаль в процессе работы приложения (первый способ не позволит изменить локаль так просто, так как БД создается один раз в начале работы приложения и для смены ее придется апгрейдить)